# How to rewrite document.getElementsByTagName(); with XPath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Could you help me to rewrite the following piece of code using XPath?

```
        final Document document = XMLUtil.buildDocFromString(xmlString);
        final NodeList ruleNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("ruleDefinition");
        for (int i = 0; i < ruleNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentElement = ruleNodeList.item(i);
            currentElement.getAttributes().getNamedItem("updatedBy").setNodeValue(user);
        }
        final NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("configuration");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            final Node currentElement = nodeList.item(i);
            if (currentElement.getAttributes().getNamedItem("type").getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue().equals("flag")) {
                currentElement.getChildNodes().item(0).setNodeValue(byPassManualReviewFlag ? "Y" : "N");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Simple question: why do you want to change?

Comment: I was asked to do it. I hate XML and everything related to it, so I didn’t try to dig deeper and ask why

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ruleDefinition");
```

Interms of *XPath* you can use:

```
document.evaluate('//ruleDefinition', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

Comment: And how to refactor the rest?

Comment: Ummm, your question heading was _rewrite document.getElementsByTagName(); with XPath?_ but if you want us to rewrite the entire block that would be _too broad_.

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't work. document.evaluate() doesn't compile